# Application stopped unexpectedly on launch - no compilation errors in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, crash

My application for Android (API level 8+) is compiled without any error messages in Eclipse.

The console says:

```
[2011-08-04 16:10:50 - PROJECT_NAME] Android Launch!
[2011-08-04 16:10:50 - PROJECT_NAME] adb is running normally.
[2011-08-04 16:10:50 - PROJECT_NAME] Performing PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity activity launch
[2011-08-04 16:10:52 - PROJECT_NAME] Uploading PROJECT_NAME.apk onto device '80A354043048365763'
[2011-08-04 16:10:52 - PROJECT_NAME] Installing PROJECT_NAME.apk...
[2011-08-04 16:10:55 - PROJECT_NAME] Success!
[2011-08-04 16:10:55 - PROJECT_NAME] Starting activity PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity on device DEVICE_ID
[2011-08-04 16:10:56 - PROJECT_NAME] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=PACKAGE_NAME/.MainActivity }
```

This is what is always displayed there. The application is then started on my USB-connected Android device.

It used to work fine, until at some point in the developing process the following message appeared:.

```
Sorry! The application Messages (process PACKAGE_NAME) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Force close.
```

In the background, there is the application window - but without any GUI elements: no buttons, no text. Just the application's title on the top.

I don't know why this message appears. I cannot test my application anymore. And - as I already said - there are no errors in Eclipse.

Logcat says the following:

```
08-04 16:35:27.666: INFO/ActivityManager(2365): Force stopping package PACKAGE_NAME uid=10077
08-04 16:35:27.676: INFO/ActivityManager(2365): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=PACKAGE_NAME/.MainActivity }
08-04 16:35:27.726: WARN/Flex(2448): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:27.766: INFO/ActivityManager(2365): Start proc PACKAGE_NAME for activity PACKAGE_NAME/.MainActivity: pid=4262 uid=10077 gids={3003}
08-04 16:35:27.916: WARN/ActivityThread(4262): Application PACKAGE_NAME is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
08-04 16:35:27.926: INFO/System.out(4262): Sending WAIT chunk
08-04 16:35:28.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:28.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:28.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:28.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:28.016: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
08-04 16:35:28.016: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=26203 curHPLMN=26203
08-04 16:35:28.126: INFO/System.out(4262): Debugger has connected
08-04 16:35:28.136: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:28.336: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:28.536: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:28.736: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:28.936: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:29.141: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:29.336: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:29.539: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:29.739: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:29.945: INFO/System.out(4262): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-04 16:35:30.146: INFO/System.out(4262): debugger has settled (1340)
08-04 16:35:31.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:31.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:31.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:31.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:31.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
08-04 16:35:31.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=26203 curHPLMN=26203
08-04 16:35:34.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:34.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:34.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:34.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:34.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
08-04 16:35:34.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=26203 curHPLMN=26203
08-04 16:35:37.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:37.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:37.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:37.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:37.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
08-04 16:35:37.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=26203 curHPLMN=26203
08-04 16:35:37.697: WARN/ActivityManager(2365): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-04 16:35:37.894: WARN/ActivityManager(2365): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{451e5930 PACKAGE_NAME/.MainActivity}
08-04 16:35:40.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:40.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:40.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:40.016: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:40.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
08-04 16:35:40.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=26203 curHPLMN=26203
08-04 16:35:43.017: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:43.017: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:43.017: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_COUNTRY_CODE COM
08-04 16:35:43.017: WARN/Flex(2365): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE OPEN
08-04 16:35:43.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
08-04 16:35:43.026: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(2365): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=26203 curHPLMN=26203
```

I hope somebody can help me ... :) I'm almost desperate. Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit #1:**

When I run the application in Eclipse's debug mode, the error message doesn't appear. The application window appears but without any GUI elements. And I have to close the window using the HOME button. The BACK button doesn't work. And in the application settings I can choose "Force Stop". So is there any problem with threads maybe? Maybe the application got stuck?

**Edit #2:**

It doesn't seem to be an Eclipse problem or phone problem as I am still able to create a "Hello World" app. It even runs on the phone.

**Edit #3:**

My main activity starts as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
```

When I change this to ...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

... and comment out the following line, the application is shown without any error messages:

```
setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
```

**Edit #4:**

I think I can remember again what I changed before the problem occurred for the first time: I implemented the code of a [tutorial on ListViews](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) which worked fine. But then I changed the ID of the listview (see tutorial: main.xml) from "android:list" to "resultList". So this was probably the cause.

When I change it back now, the error occurrs in initiateSearch() where it says thread.notifyAll();

When I comment out this line, everything works without any errors, but the application does not what it should do anymore, of course.

Comment: What have you done since the last time it was working? It could be a lot of different things.

Comment: The last thing I did was probably adding an OnItemClickListener. But I've even tried to comment that out. Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having talked to Marco it turns out the error was to do with the id naming of the List element in the xml.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html - "...To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id '@android:id/list' ..."

---

Eclipse is a bit rubbish sometimes!!

Things I would try in order:

1. Clean projects
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Completely remove the application and data & cache from your handset
4. On your phone go in to your settings-> Applications-> Development and disable then re-enable USB Debugging
5. Restart your phone
6. Rebuild your eclipse workspace

Let me know if any of those help

Comment: Agreed - also sometimes dropping to a command line and doing 'adb kill-server' and then 'adb devices' will fix some issues I have with my devices.

Comment: Tried everything in connection, even the "adb kill-server" - it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you build a simple hello world project and try running that - see if that works?

Comment: Delete R.java. It should generate again automatically.

Comment: "Hello World" app works. No compilation error and shown on phone correctly.

Comment: Now I've also deleted the R.java - it was automatically re-created. But this didn't change anything. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a new project in eclipse and copy the files in res and src over to see if that works - if not then we can def rule out Eclipse being at fault.

Comment: Yes, copied all files from "src" and "res" to a new project. Just these files, not the manifest file or something else. And then the new project crashed as well. So it has to be an error within those files, right?

Comment: Try putting a debug marker on the first line of your main activity and run the app in debug mode - see if you can get in to the code in order to step through. If you can then you'll be able to tell where the application falls over, if it doesn't even get this far then we'll think of something else

Comment: I've tried this. And it didn't work. I've even reduced the main activity to the "Hello world" example. The only way to suppress the error is shown in my third edit (see the question). Then the application works again. But this is not what I want to do, of course.

Comment: @MarcoW. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2167/discussion-between-martyn-and-marco-w)

Comment: Actually, now it works even with a custom ListView id. But then only 1 of 2 lines is displayed. When I use android:id/list then everything works perfect :)

The change which suppresses the error was definitely surrounding thread.notifyAll() with synchronized (thread) { ... }